# I want to call/pull portions of a web page into another page

Tags: php

I have this page which displays for the visitor. The articles published in the site are ordered by dates (https://www.mycbs.biz/blog.php). I would like to "mark" the 6 most recent ones and be able to display their links calling them in another page. So far I have tried to insert them (individually) into

```
<?php
    return [     
        'q1' => '
            <p>
            </p>',
    ];
?>
```

I use

```
<?php
        $quotes = require '/blog.php';
        echo $quotes['q1'];
        $quotes = require '/blog.php';
        echo $quotes['q2'];
?>
```

to retrieve them but I can't. The result is that it loads the whole blog page. Any advice?

Comment: So, `blog.php` renders html?

Comment: Hi GetSet, almost all the site consists of php web pages.

Comment: Well since you have that source to `blog.php`, could you post the portion that concerns blog entries specifically? If you can't post here, then what you will need to do in a nutshell, is create a php function that returned all blog posts or a single blog post by id (or both), either prerendered as html or just the data itself and render later. You would want to create these functions in a separate file from `blog.php`.

Comment: Feel free to post back here with what functions you came up with. I'd like to take a look. But if its working, all good and no need.

Comment: Thanks again. Well, I have no clue, as I don't master PHP. What I could learn from your answer is that I can't use that function from a php pa., I've been using

Comment: Yeah, you need a file that when you `require()` it doesn't do anything. Then you call its functions to get work done. You could base it off of your existing `blog.php`. Just wrap the relevant parts in a function and return the results. Look into php arrays.

Comment: Thanks again. Well, I have no clue, as I don't master PHP. What I could learn from your answer is that I can't use that function from a php page.

I've been using php require in php web pages, that retrieves pieces of info (inside <p></p>s) using php return, or whole html pages (where my heAd or footer are).

In the first case, though, the whole source php page was devoted to store those pieces of information mentioned. I thought (erroneously) that I could do the same from a php page that actually displays content to the visitor, in this case, the blog.php page.

Comment: Yeah will just take some rewriting in those areas. However, its just a matter of getting the blog data from wherever it is stored, putting it in an array, and returning the results via the `return` statement.

Comment: Ok no problem. ..........

Comment: Improved formatting and spelling